# How can I check the color of the tab bar buttons?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Do you have an idea how can I change the gray color of this tab button to another color?This is basically the non-taped button, when the user taps it, it is changing to white.
[image]

I have tried that:

```
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.flatBlue()
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.flatWhite()
```

But it it not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `barTintColor` for the whole bar and `tintColor` for the tapped button.

```
self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

inside Appdelegate.swift

Insert code somewhere in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
}
```

Comment: should I write that in the app delegate?

Comment: in AppDelegate or Create you own TabBarClass @Dakata



You might want to use this link to understand more about tab bar. 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-exploring-tab-bar-controller--cms-25470

Answer (score 0):

The appearance proxy and tint colors won't change the color of the *Unselected* tab bar item image or text (i.e. the colors for tabs in an unselected state).  You can do so with the following.

**Image:**

Use a `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` when setting the `image` property on your `UITabBarItem`.  This will preserve the color of your image asset, allowing you to control the color rendered on unselected tabs by modifying your image (e.g. make your image a light gray).

e.g. (sorry my code snippets are Objective-C):

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"mytabimage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

**Text/label:**

Use the appearance proxy on `UITabBarItem` (Objective-C):

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

this sets the color of the tab bar item text for "Normal" states, the same trick can be used with `UIControlStateSelected` to override the color for the "Selected" state.